# Autoruns: Error changing item state: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: autorun

I'm using Autoruns v11.70, and when I try to deselect an item in the Logon tab, I receive the error:

> Error changing item state: The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

The item remains ticked, and I cannot deselected it.

Autoruns is not installed, it runs as a standalone utility.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Given your previous question, it sounds as though Skype and Teamviewer have changed the mechanism by which they start.  Look for them under another tab.

Autoruns retains a link to the blocked file within the registry.  This is in a subfolder that it creates below the normal startup folder.  If the file that is being blocked has been deleted, because the startup mechanism has changed, then Autoruns won't be able to remove its entry.

I would delete the Autoruns subfolder manually using Regedit then start again.  You're looking for both:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled
```

Comment: I deleted both subfolders, restarted, ran Autoruns, tried to delete TeamViewer, and received the same error.